# Show that $f(x) = {1\over x^n}$ is continuous in its domain, $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

> Let $n\in\Bbb N$. Show that 
>   $$
> f(x) = {1\over x^n}
> $$ is continuous in its domain.

I've recently shown that $g(x) = x^n$ is continuous everywhere in $\Bbb R$. Now I want to do the same for $1/x^n$, however, I have some doubts regarding my reasoning below.

While proving the statement for $g(x)$ I've used the fact that:
$$
|x^{n+1} - x_0^{n+1}| = |x-x_0||x^n + x^{n-1}x_0 + \cdots +x_0^{n}|
$$

Now for some neighborhood of any $x$ (say $1$) we have that:
$$
\exists M\in\Bbb R: |x^n + x^{n-1}x_0 + \cdots +x_0^{n}| \le M
$$
So if we take $\delta = \min\{{\epsilon \over M}, 1\}$ we have:
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta M < \epsilon
$$

A similar approach, however, didn't work for $f(x) = 1/x^n$. After some trials, I've considered a bit different approach. I've recently shown that $1\over x$ is continuous in its domain. Namely:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}{1\over x} = {1\over x_0}
$$

Suppose:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} {1\over x^n} = {1\over x_0^n}
$$
Multiply both sides by $\lim_{x\to x_0} 1/x$:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} {1\over x} \cdot \lim_{x\to x_0} {1\over x^n} = \lim_{x\to x_0} {1\over x} \cdot {1\over x_0^n} \iff \\
\lim_{x\to x_0} {1\over x^{n+1}} = {1\over x_0}\cdot {1\over x_0^n} = {1\over x_0^{n+1}}
$$

I have a very weird feeling after applying induction. Bet it is not legal here, is it?

So my question is: How does one show $f(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: the product of continous functions is continous.

Comment: do you know that the composition of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @zhw. I haven’t met that yet. But thanks for the hint, will take a look in that direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $|x-y|<\delta <|x|/2$, then \begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{1}{x^n}-\frac{1}{y^n} \bigg|&=
\frac{|y-x||x^{n-1}+\cdots +y^{n-1}|}{|x^ny^n|}\\&
 \leq \frac{\delta n(
|x|+\delta)^{n-1} }{|x|^n (|x|-\delta)^n}
\\&< \frac{n\delta  2\cdot 3^{n-1}  }{
|x|^{n+1} }\end{align*}